# Populate rows based on inputs on another sheet in EXcel

Tags: excel

I've gone through various examples but don't match my need.
I need to populate a sheet based on multiple cells. 
For example, in Sheet 1 C5 cell I've value 2 and in c6 I've 5 and in c7 I've 8.
Then in Sheet 2, i'll create rows in column a as "e001, e002" and after that in cell a3 "E101,....E105" and then "E401....E408"
It would be better if its not using vba as i'm not yet conversed with it.

[Sample sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a8SB.png)
[image]

[Sample sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgdLU.png)
[image]

Following is a code which i've written but not working to my expectation.

```
Public Sub InsertTagNumbers()  
    Dim ehv_breaker As Long  
    Dim row_no As Long  
    Dim breaker11kv As Long  
    Dim breaker33kv As Long  
    Dim breaker415V As Long  
    Dim breaker415E As Long  
    Dim carry11 As Long  
    Dim carry33 As Long  
    Dim carry415 As Long  
    Dim counter1 As Integer  
    Dim counter2 As Integer  

    ehv_breaker = 0
    row_no = 5
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("b5").Select

    For ehv_breaker = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c6").Value
        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(row_no, 2).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(6, 4) & 
        Format$(ehv_breaker, "00")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        row_no = row_no + 1
    Next ehv_breaker

    For breaker11kv = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c7").Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row_no, 2).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(7, 4) & 
        Format$(breaker11kv, "00")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        row_no = row_no + 1
        Next breaker11kv
    carry11 = breaker11kv

    For breaker33kv = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c8").Value
        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(row_no, 2).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(8, 4) & 
        Format$(breaker33kv, "00")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        row_no = row_no + 1
        Next breaker33kv
    carry33 = breaker33kv

    For breaker415V = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c9").Value
        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(row_no, 2).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(9, 4) & 
        Format$(breaker415V, "00")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        row_no = row_no + 1
        Next breaker415V
    carry415 = breaker415V

    For breaker415E = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c10").Value
        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(row_no, 2).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(10, 4) & 
        Format$(breaker415E, "00")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        row_no = row_no + 1
    Next breaker415E

    'For breaker11kv > breaker11kv To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c11").Value + carry11
    Do
        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(row_no, 2).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(11, 4) & 
        Format$(breaker11kv, "00")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        row_no = row_no + 1
        breaker11kv = breaker11kv + 1
    Loop Until breaker11kv > Sheets("Sheet1").Cells("c11").Value + carry11
    'Loop Until breaker11kv > Sheets("Sheet1").cells(c11").Value + carry11
    'Next breaker11kv

    For breaker33kv = breaker33kv To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c12").Value + carry33
        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(row_no, 2).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(12, 4) & 
        Format$(breaker33kv, "00")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        row_no = row_no + 1
    Next breaker33kv

    For breaker415V = breaker415V To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c13").Value + carry415
        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(row_no, 2).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(13, 4) & 
        Format$(breaker415V, "00")
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        row_no = row_no + 1
    Next breaker415V

    MsgBox "ehv_breaker=" & ehv_breaker
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*. Just note, that you **will** require VBA to automate this task. So, you should start learning some...

Comment: I'm sorry for not updating the same. However i've added the code i was working and hope someone will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your first loops look fine, then you have the `Do .. Loop Until`, which is slightly unusual.

The loops *after* that seem to be a mess:  For example:

```
For breaker33kv = breaker33kv To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c12").Value + carry33
```

How can you start an uninitialised variable as itself?  Should it start at 1?

```
For breaker33kv = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c12").Value
```

I'm also not quite sure what the `carry` variables are for?  If the plan is to group the Sync and Non-Sync breakers together, then your code should process Sheet1!11:11 straight after Sheet1!7:7, before it goes on to Sheet1!8:8